# Appending to a table using a limit query doesn't honour the limit value

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm experimenting with appending data to bigquery tables by selecting from other tables, using the command-line tool, like this;

```
bq --nosync query --max_rows 0 --batch --destination_table=mydataset.append_test 'select * from [mydataset.source_table] limit 500'
```

At this point, "source_table" has just under 5 billion rows, and "append_test" doesn't exist.

When the job completes, "append_test" has been created, but it contains 3,605 rows, instead of the 500 rows I expected. Can someone explain why this is happening?

If any bigquery admins want to investigate further, an example job id showing this behaviour is 342881999645:bqjob_r1947710924c85445_00000144ac3214f9_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is an unfortunate outcome from a design choice we made about how we return repeated fields (we flatten them). Your table has one repeated field; when you do `SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 500`, the first 500 rows are returned. We then apply flattening to those rows, so that we store one row per repeated element. So if you ran a SELECT * query on a table with the following data (one field a that has a single value, one field x that has a repeated value)

```
{a1, [x1, x2]},
{a2, [x3, x4]}
```

You'd get the following result after flattening:

```
{a1, x1},
{a1, x2},
{a2, x3},
{a2, x4},
```

The kicker is that this would only count as 2 rows from a LIMIT perspective. We realize that this is not what most people would want or expect. The good news is that we are considering ways to fix it. There are a couple of reasons why it is tricky, and we also would need to make sure that any fix would be backwards compatible so that people don't get surprised by the change (likely we'd add a flag that says 'flatten_results' and default it to true).

In the mean time, if you really only want 500 values back, you can apply an explicit flatten:

```
SELECT * from FLATTEN(t1, field) LIMIT 500;
```